# How to amplify this signal?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

Signal captured after 1 μF capacitor so want to amplify it to measure the width of pulse.

Negative pulse injected to 12 VDC then after it connect 1 μF + then 1 μF - connected to pullup resistor as 10k so this signal get it from 1 μF.

Note: I want to measure negative signal width.

[image]

[image]

Comment: used op-amp solved the issue thanks for your time

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137713/discussion-on-question-by-smarta-how-to-amplify-this-signal).

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

This scope has a bandwidth of 200 kHz. That pulse most likely is too short to be displayed properly using it.
In fact it's possible to enlarge a pulse multiple times. But it's utterly complex and you'll find it easier to buy a better scope. But here's a method that could work and hopefully demonstrates, why it can't be recommended.

You could build a circuit which uses an integrator.
Feed the input pulse through a schmitt-trigger. At the output of it you will get the pulse but with a fixed voltage. Feed this into the integrator.

Then you will have to trigger on the falling slope of the pulse and switch (using a average complex logic circuit) the input of the integrator to a negative input voltage. This negative voltage should be an exact fraction (e.g. 10th) of the output of the schmitt-trigger. When the output of the integrator reaches 0V again, another logic should switch its input off.

You will get two slopes. The first, rising slope will have the width of your original pulse, while the second, falling slope will have the multiple width (e.g. 10 times) of the original pulse.

Now, while that might work, it isn't easy, as you have to deal with imprecision at all points. The range of expansion is very limited as you have to reduce the negative voltage close to -0 to get greater dilation.

And it won't work on any other signal than a single, isolated pulse.

Comment: @Smarta You keep repeating that but without a schematic, no one of us will be able to know what you are measuring.

Comment: @winny another mcu board inject pulse over dc wire so the question is if connect the end of 1uf to schmitt triger so can measure pulse width from schmitt triger output?

Comment: @Smarta Post schematic. And please simulate it.

Comment: With 200 KHz bandwidth, the scope should be able to display a pulse as narrow as 20 uSec and it has a 10 uSec / div sweep. I have the same scope, but mine does not have the measurement display.